# R: change timedate <chr> to separate date <date> and time<hms>

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a date column that's output is in chr format:

```
glimpse(november$start_at): 
chr [1:337735] "01/11/2022 00:00" "01/11/2022 00:00" "01/11/2022 00:00" "01/11/2022 00:00" "01/11/2022 00:01" "01/11/2022 06:43"
```

I want to separate this into 2 separate date and time columns.
the start_date should be in date format and the start time should be in time(hms) format. Note, the time in start_at only has hours and minutes no seconds, so I will just assume seconds as 00 for all data in november data frame. I want my output to like this:

```
start_date  start_Time 
2022/11/01  02:04:00
.
.
.
```

so far I have done the date part:

```
november$start_date <- as.Date(format(as.Date(november$started_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d"))

str(november$start_date) 
 start_date     : Date[1:337735], format: "2022-11-01" "2022-11-01" "2022-11-01" "2022-11-01"
```

the problem is that when I run the code for the time I get 00:00:00 for everything or NA for everything..

```
format(as.POSIXct(november$started_at), format = "%H:%M:%S")

 [1] "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"

as.Date(parse_date_time(november$started_at,"dmy"))

 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 

thanks in advanced.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

november <- tibble(
  start_at = c(
    "01/11/2022 00:00",
    "01/11/2022 00:00",
    "01/11/2022 00:00",
    "01/11/2022 00:00",
    "01/11/2022 00:01",
    "01/11/2022 06:43"
  )
)

# A tibble: 6 × 1
  start_at        
  <chr>           
1 01/11/2022 00:00
2 01/11/2022 00:00
3 01/11/2022 00:00
4 01/11/2022 00:00
5 01/11/2022 00:01
6 01/11/2022 06:43
```

Mutate new columns

```
november %>% 
  mutate(
    start_date = as_date(mdy_hm(start_at)), 
    start_time = as_hms(mdy_hm(start_at))
  )

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  start_at         start_date start_time
  <chr>            <date>     <time>    
1 01/11/2022 00:00 2022-01-11 00:00     
2 01/11/2022 00:00 2022-01-11 00:00     
3 01/11/2022 00:00 2022-01-11 00:00     
4 01/11/2022 00:00 2022-01-11 00:00     
5 01/11/2022 00:01 2022-01-11 00:01     
6 01/11/2022 06:43 2022-01-11 06:43
```

Comment: that worked nicely.. now to convert the start_time to the correct data type.
thanks

Comment: @NabeelEl-Habbash Editted - time is in correct format

Comment: I need it in 3 parts. H:M:S, and the date as %Y-%m-%d

Comment: You mention 3 but listed up time (HMS) and date (Ymd)? And literally how my answer is constructed

Comment: 2022-01-11 00:00 this is your answer
I want it:
2022-11-01 00:00:00

Comment: There would be seconds there if your data had seconds

Answer (score 1):

Basically using `strptime` and `strsplit` at the space but selecting the second elements.

```
transform(df, x=NULL, date=strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) |>
  {\(.) transform(., time=sapply(strsplit(as.character(date), ' '), `[`, 2))}()
#   y                date     time
# 1 0 2022-11-01 00:00:00 00:00:00
# 2 0 2022-11-01 00:00:00 00:00:00
# 3 0 2022-11-01 00:00:00 00:00:00
# 4 0 2022-11-01 00:00:00 00:00:00
# 5 0 2022-11-01 00:01:00 00:01:00
# 6 0 2022-11-01 06:43:00 06:43:00
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("01/11/2022 00:00", "01/11/2022 00:00", 
"01/11/2022 00:00", "01/11/2022 00:00", "01/11/2022 00:01", "01/11/2022 06:43"
), y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: the time comes out wrong. I want it in 3 parts. H:M:S, and the date as %Y-%m-%d

14:02:00

Comment: @NabeelEl-Habbash Fine, see update.

Comment: honestly I don't have a clue what's happening here..

Comment: @NabeelEl-Habbash Sorry, it got a little hacky. I simplified it a bit. First, we `strptime` the `x` column into the desired `"POSIXct"` time format, where `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'` deciphers the given format. Simultaneously  we set `x` to `NULL` because we don't need it anymore. Then we `|>`  pipe it into `susbtring` which leaves everything from the `12`th character on to get the time.